# calling method that contains if/else

Tags: if-statement, methods, user-input, java.util.scanner

This is a fairly basic question but as a new Java student it's stumped me. This a practice problem that I'm working on and can't figure out how to call the hotOrColdOutside method into the main. As of now it's not compiling and asking for a return but my instructions specify there is no arguments or return in this instance. I feel like this is something simple that I know but is going over my head at the moment and any help in correcting this will be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class TempExp
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       String answer = outsideTemp();
       System.out.print(answer);
   }//end main
   public static String outsideTemp()
   {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("What is the temperature outside: ");
       int userIn = input.nextInt();
       if(userIn >= 80)
       {
          System.out.print("It is very hot outside.");
       }
       else if(userIn >= 60)
       {
          System.out.print("It is very nice outside.");
       }
       else
       {
          System.out.print("It is very cold outside.");
       }//end if/else           
    }//end method   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function

```
public static String outsideTemp()
```

returns a `String`.  The main function doesn't return anything, though.

You'll want something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class TempExp
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       String answer = outsideTemp();
       System.out.print(answer);
   }//end main

   public static String outsideTemp()
   {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("What is the temperature outside: ");
       int userIn = input.nextInt();
       if(userIn >= 80)
       {
          return "It is very hot outside.";
       }
       else if(userIn >= 60)
       {
          return "It is very nice outside.";
       }
       else
       {
          return "It is very cold outside.";
       }//end if/else           
    }//end method   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you say your instructions (I'm guessing you mean the assignment?) say there are no arguments or returns, you need to replace the `String` part of the function definition of `outsideTemp()` with `void`. Because it will not return anything, your `main` function will also need to be changed to not expect anything to be returned.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    outsideTemp();
}//end main

public static void outsideTemp()
{
    ... // this all stays exactly how it is now
}
```

However, if you do mean to return a string, use John's answer